# MySQL multiple table sum

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I want to list customer with balance.
I have 3 table,

Customers, Sales, Payments

Customer table

---

```
id name    lastname
1  John    Doe
2  Example Customer
3  NonBaloance User
```

---

Sales Table

```
id customer_id amount
1  1           1500
2  2           300
```

---

Payments Table

```
id sales_id amount
1  1        500
2  1        700
3  2        200
```

I need list customers order by balance (sales amount count - payments amount count)

example result

```
id name       lastme   balance
1  John       Doe      300
2  Example    Customer 100
3  NonBalance User     0
```

is it possible?

Comment: "Is it possible?"  Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery to compute the balance, like so:

```
select
    c.*,
    coalesce(
        (
            select sum(
                s.amount 
                - (select coalesce(sum(p.amount), 0) from payments p where p.sales_id = s.id)
            )
            from sales s
            where s.customer_id = c.id
        ), 
        0
    ) balance
from customer c
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5394ae15981f1ad0ea3fc311a0694e2f)**:

```
id | name        | lastname | balance
-: | :---------- | :------- | ------:
 1 | John        | Doe      |     300
 2 | Example     | Customer |     100
 3 | NonBaloance | User     |       0
```